# file permission in dir

Tags: perl

How can I find a file, user owned by `tree` and group owned by `tree`? And how can I find a whole directory inside which files are owned by `tree`?

Comment: I edited your question to clarify what (I believe) you mean. (The choice of "tree" as the user/group name caught me off guard, since it can also mean a directory structure...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module is a standard Perl module (i.e., it is available on all installations of Perl). You can use File::Find to go through a directory tree and search for the file you want.

To use, you create a `wanted` subroutine that parses the files, then have the `find` subroutine include that `wanted` routine in its call. The `File::Find` module is a bit klutzy because it was originally only meant to use for the [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html) command.

Here's some completely untested code. Notice that you do yucky stuff like using global variables and package variables. It's one of the reasons I don't like `File::Find`.

```
use File::Find;
our $myUid = getpwnam('tree');
our $muGid = getgrnam('tree');
find (\&wanted, @dirList);

sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size, $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat($File::Find::name);
    next if (not -f $File::Find::name);
    next if ($uid != $myUid);
    next if ($gid != $myGid);
    print qq(File "$File::Find::name" is owned by group 'tree' and user 'tree'\n);
}
```

I wrote my own `File::Find` called `File::OFind` because it's more object oriented. You can get that from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/File_Find.tar.gz). It's a bit easier to understand. (Again, completely untested):

```
use File::OFind;
# Really should test if these return something
my $myUid = getpwnam('tree');
my $muGid = getgrnam('tree');

# Create your directory search object
my $find = File::OFind->new(STAT => 1, $directory);

# Now keep looping and examining each file
while($find->Next) {
   next if ($find->Uid != $myUid);
   next if ($find->Gid != $myGid);
   next if ($find->Type ne "f");   #Is this a file?
   print $find->Name . " is owned by group and user tree\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin Perl functions you will need to accomplish this task include [`getpwnam`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#getpwnam), [`getgrnam`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#getgrnam), and [`stat`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#stat).

```
 ($name,$passwd,$uid,$gid,
   $quota,$comment,$gcos,$dir,$shell,$expire) = getpwnam 'tree';
```

will return a lot of useful information about the user `tree`. For this task you will be particularly interested in the `$uid` field. Likewise,

```
($name,$passwd,$gid,$members) = getgrnam 'tree';
```

retrieves data about the group `tree`. You will be most interested in the `$gid` field. Finally, the [`stat`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#stat) function

```
($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
   $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
       = stat($filename);
```

returns a 13-element array with system information about a file (or a directory). For your task, you are looking for files such that the user and group ids returned from `stat($filename)` match the user and group ids returned from `getpwnam` and `getgrnam`.

Answer (score 0):

File::Find::Rule makes this clean and simple:

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my $uid_tree = getpwnam('tree');
my $gid_tree = getgrnam('tree');

my @files =
   File::Find::Rule
   ->file()
   ->uid($uid_tree)
   ->gid($gid_tree)
   ->in('.');
```

Ref:

- [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind%3A%3ARule)
- [getpw* and getgr*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwuid.html)